# Python: Solution for high int-precision needed (generate primes)

Tags: python, math, int, decimal, primes

at the moment I try to implement a generate_random_prime()-function from the algorithm shown in FIPS186-4 from NIST (Appendix B3.2.1), see [here](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.186-4.pdf).

But there seems a big problem with step 4.4 (if p < sqrt(2)*(2**((nlen/2)-1)), because of the precision in Python.

to show the relevant part and problem of my code, see this example:

```
import os
from decimal import Decimal
import math

for i in range(100):
    nlen = 2048 #my key-size should be 2048bit
    p = int.from_bytes(os.urandom(int(2048/2/8)), byteorder = "little") #see Ann1 and Ann2

    print(p < Decimal(math.sqrt(2))*(Decimal(2**(int(2048/2))) - 1)
```

Ann1: 2048/2/8 because of bytes
Ann2: I know that os.urandom is not the best generator - I will later use an approved one... for the testing phase it should be acceptable I think...

The result is always "True" - so the algorithm will never leave step 4.4.

I think the problem is `Decimal(math.sqrt(2))*(Decimal(2**(int(2048/2))) - 1)`, because the result of this is `Decimal('2.542322012307292741109308792E+308')`. Convert to int via `int(Decimal(math.sqrt(2))*(Decimal(2**(int(2048/2))) - 1))`, the result will be

```
254232201230729274110930879200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

It is rounded up! - Is this the reason for the always True result? I think in this case it will never be possible to get a p less than `Decimal(math.sqrt(2))*(Decimal(2**(int(2048/2))) - 1)`

How can I solve this problem?

__
edit: found a mistake:
`Decimal(math.sqrt(2))*(Decimal(2**(int(2048/2))) - 1)` should be `Decimal(math.sqrt(2))*(Decimal(2**(int(2048/2-1))))`, so the result of this should be `Decimal('1.271161006153646370554654396E+308')` instead of `Decimal('2.542322012307292741109308791E+308')`

Comment: Why are you using decimal at all?

Comment: I am not a very advanced python programmer... but in some cases I got error because of big ints and decimal, so I tried to use decimal in any cases...

Comment: Every step in that algorithm, including step 4.4, is assumed to be implemented using integers. Not float, not decimal, just integer. You don't need to have a highly accurate approximation to sqrt(2)*(...), you just need a reasonably accurate **upper bound** that's fast to compute. Or you could just pre-compute this value for common prime sizes like 1024 bits and 2048 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constantly converting between floats, integers and `Decimal`. Drop all use of `float`; this includes not using functions that produce `float` values, such as `math.sqrt()`.

Stick to `Decimal` objects instead, and only convert the final value to an integer:

```
int(Decimal(2).sqrt() * 2 ** ((nlen // 2) - 1))
```

Note the use of `//`, to use integer division, not true division (producing floats again).